# Apache poi put encode in hiperlink when i write in sheet

Tags: excel, hyperlink, apache-poi

I have a workbook, and when i write values in the sheets hiperlinks are encoded and links doesn´t works

Sample:

Product List the link turn in -> Product%20List, excel doesn´t works with this hyperlink

This encode included space and special chars like ç

How i ignore encode in hyperlinks in apache poi?

Comment: A hyperlink `URI` must be URI encoded. So Product%20List is absolutely correct in a hyperlink URI. Your problem must be elsewhere. Please do describing your problem more clearly. What code are you using to create a hyperlink in `Excel`? What is the exact result?

Comment: @AxelRichter i don´t create a link, i wrote values in a existent sheet with hyperlink with shape (image + link) just with hyperlink works fine, but when sheet has hiyperlink with shape the encode is applied

Comment: @AxelRichter the excel throw message that reference is invalid.

Comment: To be able to help We need [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce your issue. Else no help possible.

Comment: The current code is:


The excel file before write:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=17GbKxNeGR16237Ys_TNXaqhfcnzlXs8u
The shape hyperlink stop working in microsoft excel.
The shape hyperlink redirect to another tab.
The cell hyperlink still working...

Comment: @AxelRichter the current code
`code`
public class TestShapeHyperlink {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  
  InputStream in = TestShapeHyperlink.class.getResourceAsStream("before-read-write-using-apache-poi.xlsm");
  Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(in);
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  wb.write(baos);
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("after-read-write-using-apache-poi.xlsm");
  fos.write(baos.toByteArray());
  fos.close();
  System.out.println("fim");

 }
}
`code`

Comment: If you look at your comments, are they readable for you? Please **edit** your question and provide all necessary informations there. There also proper code formatting is possible.

Comment: inline `public class TestShapeHyperlink {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  
  InputStream in = TestShapeHyperlink.class.getResourceAsStream("before-read-write-using-apache-poi.xlsm");
  Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(in);
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  wb.write(baos);
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("after-read-write-using-apache-poi.xlsm");
  fos.write(baos.toByteArray());
  fos.close();
  System.out.println("fim");

 }
}`